# Output of fa2latex command from psych causing LaTeX error in pandoc

Tags: latex, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc, psych

I am writing a report using knitr in RStudio. Also using the psych package for factor analysis:

````
```{r, results='asis'}
library(psych)
data(Thurstone)
fa.Thurstone<-fa(Thurstone)
fa2latex(fa.Thurstone)
```
````

When I run this code chunk it causes an error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Unknown float option `d'.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.124 \begin{scriptsize} \begin{table}[htdp]

pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
```

When I save the TeX code it runs fine in LaTeX, but not in knitr.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Comment: I solved this with a workaround. Created a new function fa3latex by copying the R code for the fa2latex function and remove the "d" in the table declaration:

header <- paste("\\begin{",font.size,"} \\begin{table}[htp]",
"\\caption{",caption,"}

@william-revelle

Comment: That was a bug in psych.  It is now fixed in version 1.5.8.  I encourage people who find bugs like this to let me know as well as writing to stack overflow.

Comment: Thanks William, much appreciated.