# Printing readable factor analysis output in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, psych

I have to print readable factor analysis output in an Rmarkdown document (can ultimately be pdf, word or html), and I am having real trouble doing this. I had this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48175808/fa2latex-produces-latex-code-that-does-not-compile-when-produced-in-a-rmarkdown). I am running psych version 1.8.12.

Reproducible code is below, but I have also put up a github respository here:

Note, when I run `results='markup'` the pdf compiles, but the table is not readable: it prints the latex code. When I run `results='asis'`, an error is returned `! LaTeX Error: \caption outside float.`

I am much less familiar with the packages like kabel and texreg. Would those be an option?
`

---

`````
title: "Factor Analysis Test"
author: "Simon Kiss"
date: '2019-06-07'
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r}
library(psych)
```

```{r}
data('Thurstone')
```
```{r}
mod<-fa(Thurstone, 3)
```
```{r results='markup'} 
fa2latex(mod)
````
`````

Comment: what kind of table do you want to print factor loadings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to output a table make sure to convert it to a dataframe first.

````
title: "Factor Analysis Test"
author: "Simon Kiss"
date: '2019-06-07'
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r}
library(psych)
```

```{r}
data('Thurstone')
```

```{r}
mod<-fa(Thurstone, 3)
```
```{r results='markup'} 
knitr::kable(data.frame(psych::fa.sort(mod$loadings)[1:8,]))
````

Comment: OK, I can do that. but it would be nice to figure out a way to print the fa2latex code in the markdown document. fa2latex has some really nice features (e.g. supressing factor loadings lower than a value, bolding some values) that really help its readabiility.

Answer (score 1):

The Error is in the fa2latex-output. For some bizarre reason, it changes `scriptsize` into `s\iptsize`.
The following changes fix the output:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r}
library(psych)
```


```{r}
data('Thurstone')
```
```{r}
mod<-fa(Thurstone, 3)
```
```{r, results='asis'} 
a <- fa2latex(mod, silent = T)
cat(gsub('s\\iptsize','scriptsize',a))
```
````

### EDIT

The error just stopped to be reproducible for me, not sure what is going on. 
Suddenly

````
```{r, results='asis'} 
a <- fa2latex(mod, silent = F)
```
````

*does* work as intended

Answer (score 0):

in that case you need to add the output of the fa2latex(mod) directly into the document and not inside `{r results='markup'}` and then produce a pdf not an html or a doc. copy and paste the code bellow into an Rmd document and see what happens.

````
---
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
  word_document: default
---
title: "Factor Analysis Test"
author: "Simon Kiss"
date: '2019-06-07'
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r}
library(psych)
```

```{r}
data('Thurstone')
```

```{r}
mod<-fa(Thurstone, 3)
```

% Called in the psych package  fa2latex % Called in the psych package  mod 
\begin{table}[htpb]\caption{fa2latex}
\begin{center}
\begin{scriptsize} 
\begin{tabular} {l r r r r r r }
 \multicolumn{ 6 }{l}{ A factor analysis table from the psych package in R } \cr 
 \hline Variable  &   MR1  &  MR2  &  MR3  &  h2  &  u2  &  com \cr 
  \hline 
Sentences   &  \bf{ 0.90}  &  -0.03  &   0.04  &  0.82  &  0.18  &  1.01 \cr 
 Vocabulary   &  \bf{ 0.89}  &   0.06  &  -0.03  &  0.84  &  0.16  &  1.01 \cr 
 Sent.Completion   &  \bf{ 0.84}  &   0.03  &   0.00  &  0.74  &  0.26  &  1.00 \cr 
 First.Letters   &   0.00  &  \bf{ 0.85}  &   0.00  &  0.73  &  0.27  &  1.00 \cr 
 Four.Letter.Words   &  -0.02  &  \bf{ 0.75}  &   0.10  &  0.63  &  0.37  &  1.04 \cr 
 Suffixes   &   0.18  &  \bf{ 0.63}  &  -0.08  &  0.50  &  0.50  &  1.20 \cr 
 Letter.Series   &   0.03  &  -0.01  &  \bf{ 0.84}  &  0.73  &  0.27  &  1.00 \cr 
 Pedigrees   &  \bf{ 0.38}  &  -0.05  &  \bf{ 0.46}  &  0.51  &  0.49  &  1.96 \cr 
 Letter.Group   &  -0.06  &   0.21  &  \bf{ 0.63}  &  0.52  &  0.48  &  1.25 \cr 
\hline \cr SS loadings & 2.65 &  1.87 &  1.49 &  \cr  
\cr 
            \hline \cr 
MR1   & 1.00 & 0.59 & 0.53 \cr 
 MR2   & 0.59 & 1.00 & 0.52 \cr 
 MR3   & 0.53 & 0.52 & 1.00 \cr 
 \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{scriptsize}
\end{center}
\label{default}
\end{table}
````

Comment: if this doesn't help it means I do not understand the question!

Comment: The problem with this is that it is not really  reproducible in an ideal way.  It would be nice to just call the code, rather than put in the results directly.

Comment: I just wrote it in such a fashion so that the results are displayed in the console. I have also provided an answer above which seems to have solved the problem? Was the problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's a late answer I guess, but "baap" package can solve your problem. You can create a table of factor loadings while expressing unwanted loadings. This also works fine in Rmarkdown formats.